# Where to find file in wordpress .php in which i can link google font to my website?

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts

where can i find .php file in wordpress format, which can import google font which i could use in my theme?
If there's way how can i import that font?

In example simple HTML has it in

Comment: have you tried core.php file? could you provide more details on exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: check this link https://wpsites.net/web-design/custom-fonts-wordpress-font-face-generator/

Comment: I don't have such a file as far as i know. I'm trying to import google font, so i could apply it in my CSS.

Comment: Thank you Ravinder!

Comment: You'd use google-fonts @import in your stylesheet. Or download them and use the font-face rule.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get the embed code from Google Fonts for the font you're using. Add that right after the `<head>` section of header.php. You can then use the font using stylesheet, like this:

`.h1 page-title { 
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; 
}`

Obviously, replacing 'Roboto Condensed' with whichever font you're using. It will specify in Google Fonts the exact name to use, and even give you the line to paste into stye.css. I'd recommend making those changes to header.php and style.css using a child theme so that your changes don't get overwritten when you update your theme.